# Python Looping Through Lists and Creating Dynamic Variables

Tags: python, list, pandas, for-loop

I am looping through elements of lists that vary in length and content. Here is the object (`keys`) that I use:

```
keys:
key   dims                         
1     ['site', 'channel', 'fiscal_week']
2     ['site', 'dude', 'other', 'fiscal_week']         
3     ['site', 'eng', 'dude', 'something_else', 'fiscal_week']
```

I have a for loop where I loop through `keys['dims']`:

```
for key in keys['dims']:
    get desired output (see below)
```

I would like for this loop to output variables that I can use to identify columns in a pandas dataframe. For example, for `key = 1`, I would like to have this completed during the loop:

```
D1 = 'site'
D2 = 'channel'
D3 = 'fiscal_week'
```

When I get to `key = 2`, I will need to overwrite these variables, yielding:

```
D1 = 'site'
D2 = 'dude'
D3 = 'other'
D4 = 'fiscal_week'
```

My ultimate goal is to then use these variables like this:

```
df[D1]+df[D2]...
```

Here is my failed attempt:

```
for key in keys['dims']:
    print key
    d = {}
    i = 1
    for dim in key:
        d['D{0}'.format(i)]=dim
        print d        
        i +=1
```

This didn't work because it ended up giving this output:

```
['site', 'channel', 'fiscal_week']
{'D1': 'site'}
{'D2': 'channel', 'D1': 'site'}
{'D2': 'channel', 'D3': 'fiscal_week', 'D1': 'site'}
['site', 'dude', 'other', 'fiscal_week']
...etc.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Don't try to create dynamic variables. Put the values in a list or in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=yourdf.dims.values.tolist(),index=yourdf.key)
df.columns+=1
df=df.add_prefix('D')

df['D1']
Out[537]: 
key
1    site
2    site
3    site
Name: D1, dtype: object

df
Out[538]: 
       D1       D2           D3              D4           D5
key                                                         
1    site  channel  fiscal_week            None         None
2    site     dude        other     fiscal_week         None
3    site      eng         dude  something_else  fiscal_week
```

If you want it to be dictionary

```
d = df.to_dict('index')
```

Comment: Thanks @Wen! This helped tremendously!